# Open About App window programmatically on macOS

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsapplication

On Mac OS X, every app has an "About" window, which can be opened by clicking `About [appname]` in the `[appname]` menu in the menu bar.

I'd like to open this window programmatically. Is this possible?

EG: The About button for iTunes:

[image: iTunes About Menu Item]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `About` menu item is connected to the `orderFrontStandardAboutPanel` method of `NSApplication`, you can call it programmatically with

```
[NSApp orderFrontStandardAboutPanel:self]; // or nil as parameter
```

or in Swift

```
NSApp.orderFrontStandardAboutPanel(self) // or nil as parameter
```